# Pepper robot installation error ( naoqi_driver: No definition of [boost] for OS version [] )

Tags: ros, nao-robot, pepper

I try to install ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04 for pepper robot.
After installation indigo and naoqi, I have typed every command on [pepper/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pepper/Tutorials) for pepper ros packages.
Altough previously command was successful, I have got error with this line.

```
rosdep install -i -y --from-paths ./naoqi_driver
```

Command line error is:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
naoqi_driver: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that rosdep fails to detect your OS correctly, preventing it from finding the Ubuntu boost libs. You should try to specify your OS with the --os flag:

```
rosdep install -i -y --os=ubuntu:trusty --from-paths ./naoqi_driver
```